# Best way for images css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Oops, wrong snippet– had to change it back. Creating new question now

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to do this? As you've seen selecting elements by their CSS properties is going to be both slow and difficult to maintain.

Comment: Can we check your complicated code?

Comment: $(":image:visible").addClass("myclassName");

Comment: Show us your 95% complicated script and CSS . Let us understand what you have done and then we shall try to find a solution for your problem.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/image-selector/

Comment: @Andries ah ok. However that only selects `img` and `[type="image"]` elements, not where the `background-image` has been set.

Comment: i've posted an answer, but you're right

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [Document.images](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/images)

Comment: This doesn't find elements where a `background-image` has been set on it through, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = $("*").filter(function() {
    return $(this).is(":image") || $(this).css('background-image') != "none";
}).filter(":visible");
```